# Can we add google and facebook login integration in websites for user login using JSP also?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, jsp

I want to integrate **facebook** and **google** login in my website (under construction) , can i do it using **JSP**? Because i've never seen any website using jsp for facebook login.
I want to use JSP because my website back-end will be done using JSP?
Also tell if there exists any way if i can use both **JSP** and **PHP** ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it. Both Facebook and G+ provide JavaScript SDKs for logging into your app.

Reference:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in#before_you_begin

Comment: Much appreciated cuong.. Thanks